# Iterative Deepening Search python implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, graph, tree

I am trying to implement the Iterative Deepening Search with python but I have a problem with setting the depth level here is the [Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1Zi6.png) i am trying to implement and here is the code I included the DFS algorithm code since "Visited" is the answer of the last level in the IDS I want the code to print the DFS of each level of the Tree mentioned in the png

```
paths = {
    5: [3, 7],
    7: [8],
    3: [2, 4],
    4: [8],
    8: [],
    2: []
}
def ids(graph, start,target):
    depth = 1
    bottom_reached = False
    while not bottom_reached:
        result, bottom_reached = ids_rec(graph,start,target,0,depth)
        if result is not None:
            return result
        depth *= 2
        print("Increasing depth to " + str(depth))
    return None
def ids_rec(graph,start2,target,current_depth,max_depth):
    print(f"visting node {start2}")
    if start2 == target:
        return start2, True
    if current_depth == max_depth:
        print("maximum depth reached")
        if not graph.get(start2):
            return None, False
        else:
            return None, True
    bottom_reached = True
    for i in graph[start2]:
        result,bottom_reached_rec = ids_rec(graph, i,target,current_depth+1,max_depth)
        if result is not None:
            return result, True
        bottom_reached = bottom_reached and bottom_reached_rec
    return None, bottom_reached
ids(paths, 5,8)
# Depth First Search Code
done = False
# visited = []
# 
# 
# def dfs(graph, start, end):
#     global done
#     if start not in visited:
#         if not done:
#             visited.append(start)
#         if start == end:
#             done = True
#             return
#         for i in graph[start]:
#             dfs(graph, i, end)
# 
# 
# dfs(paths, 5, 8)
# print(visited)
```